# ampersand (&) vs group zero (\0)

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Is there ever any difference between & and \0 in the replacement of a substitute?

```
$ echo a b c | sed 's/\(a\) b \(c\)/&/'
a b c

$ echo a b c | sed 's/\(a\) b \(c\)/\0/'
a b c
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see `\0` documented in POSIX sed manual, gnu sed manual, or `info sed` on linux. So, I'm not sure how portable that is. `&`, on the other hand, should work everywhere.

Comment: In a non-GNU `sed`, it produces just `0`, which is what I would assume it would do. I'm a bit surprised that GNU `sed` treats it as `&`.

Comment: vim also supports both `\0` and `&`, Ruby supports `\0` and `\&`, Python supports `\g<0>`, etc.. so, probably it is supported in `GNU sed` to be more compatible?

Comment: Perl, on the other hand, stores the program name in `$0` and interprets `\0` as the null byte.